# convert an input string to an integer

Tags: ruby, string, integer, decimal

I need to convert an input string to an integer using a get_integer_from_string() function.
I am using Ruby 
and I have this schedule.

[image]

based on the schedule we need to covert from base 7 to base 10

Please note :
1- If you encounter a string with no numerical sequences, it should return zero (0).

2- The string can contain additional characters after those that form the integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior of this function.

Thank you for helping me with my homework.

Comment: This is not a base 6 system, it's base 7. Do you know how to convert numbers between bases?

Comment: @TimPietzcker actually now i'm still new in ruby thanks

Answer (score 5):

As Tim pointed out above, your table shows base 7, not 6. Both `String#to_i` and `Fixnum#to_s` take an optional radix (base) argument:

```
p "020".to_i(7)
# => 14
p 14.to_s(7)
# => "20"
```

In order to deal with trailing characters that aren't 0-6, `String#slice` (a.k.a. `String#[]`) works well:

```
expr = /^[0-6]*/

p "72"[expr].to_i(7)
# => 0
p "0202xyz"[expr].to_i(7)
# => 100
p "27"[expr].to_i(7)
# => 2
```

Comment: Regarding part 2 of the question, `"020cat".to_i(7) #=> 14`, but also `"72".to_i(7) #=> 0` because base 7 does not use a digit 7 (or 8 or 9), so this is no different than `"x2".to_i(7) #=> 0`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland and `"27".to_i(7)` is apparently `2`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is convert the string (which represents a base 7 number) to a base 10 integer. This can be done via

```
"021".to_i(7)
# => 15
```

Please see the [Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) of Ruby String class for the method to_i()

Comment: @Steve def get_integer_from_string(str)
  return 0 if (/^(?<num>\d+)$/ =~ str).nil?
  result = 0
  str.reverse.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
    tmp = char.to_i * 7**index
    result += tmp
  end
  result rescue 0
end

Answer (score 0):

i made this not sure if it's right

```
def get_integer_from_string(str)
  return 0 if (/^(?<num>\d+)$/ =~ str).nil?
  result = 0
  str.reverse.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
    tmp = char.to_i * 7**index
    result += tmp
  end
  result rescue 0
end
```